# Angular Focusout event is not working properly with table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table.Each row has `html` elements like `input` and `span`.
What I am trying to do is triggering an event (`focusout`) after I focused out of current row.But it is not working properly, it is triggering whenever I focus any column of current row.
To resolve events, I created a directive named `focus-out-directive` and used as below

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list"  focus-out-directive>
```

you can see full code of what I am working on is in this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlzqqw)

Comment: focusout is the property of input, Try adding the same directive into the input field

Comment: but this is the problem I've already encountered.I want to prevent to `focusout` event  into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `focusout` property on a `tr`, it will get triggered for child `input` elements as well. The best way to resolve this issue is to have a property in the directive containing the row index of the last focused cell.

`event.target` gives you the current `input` element, two parents above is the `tr` element which you can then use to get the current row index.

```js
export class FocusOutDirective {
        @Output() onFocusOut: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<false>();
        lastFocusedCellRowIndex: number = -1;
    
        @HostListener("focusout", ["$event"])
        public onListenerTriggered(event: any): void {
            let currentFocusedRowIndex = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            
            if(this.lastFocusedCellRowIndex != currentFocusedRowIndex){
                this.lastFocusedCellRowIndex = currentFocusedRowIndex;
                this.onFocusOut.emit(true);
                console.log('focus out of row');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is good way to handle it.but not working properly if I focus other column of row.Then focus another row.